# Is the additive group of rationals quotiented out by the integers isomorphic to the additive group of rationals?

Tags: group-theory

I'm quite new to group theory so please do help me along.

[image: Question and solution]

There are some parts of the solution I do not understand.

1) Why is the addition of n terms of (Z+q) defined as equal to Z? Shouldn't it be defined as n(Z+q)?

2) Why is the order of Z+q in Q/Z claimed to be finite? Isn't the order of an element of a group defined to be the smallest number of times an element of a group needs to be composed with itself to get the identity element back again? In the case of (Z+q) it doesn't go back to the identity element again even if you define the addition of (Z+q) n times to be equal to Z.

Thanks in advance. I'm quite puzzled by this question.

EDIT: Thanks for all of your amazing help. Turns out I had the wrong interpretation of what Z/Q represented.

Comment: Do you understand why the coset $H$ is zero in the quotient group $G/H$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ are right cosets of $\mathbb{Z}$ which partitions $\mathbb{Q}$.  So $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ gives an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Q}$ with
\begin{align*}
q \sim  p \iff \mathbb{Z} + p = \mathbb{Z} + q \iff p- q \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}

Since for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $n - 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and so the identity element in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z} + 0 = \mathbb{Z} + n = \mathbb{Z}$.  If $q = m/n \in \mathbb{Q}$ then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbb{Z} + m/n) = \mathbb{Z} + (\sum_{i=1}^n m/n) = \mathbb{Z} + m = \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*} 
since $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Hence $\mathbb{Z} + q$ has finite order in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Now ask yourself if any element in $\mathbb{Q}$ has this property.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to first consider an intuitive solution to the problem:

Suppose I take a rational $p\over q$. Then when I add it to itself $q$-many times, I get an integer (namely $p$). Now this is (probably) nonzero in $\mathbb{Q}$, but think about what role the integers serve in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$: "modding out" a group $G$ (in this case, $\mathbb{Q}$) by a normal subgroup $H$ (in this case, $\mathbb{Z}$) basically means "making every element of $H$ become zero." So we have the following idea *(which isn't quite right - see below - but is on the right track)*: $$\mbox{In $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, ${p\over q}$ added to itself $q$-many times gives zero.}$$

Put another way, the informal idea above suggests that $p\over q$ has order at most $q$ in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$." Now this isn't *quite* right: $p\over q$ isn't literally an element of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ in the first place (elements of a quotient group are cosets, not elements, of the original group). But when you go back through the argument above and make it rigorous, you get exactly the solution in the book.

Answer (score 1):

The following may help the intuition about the group $G:={\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$. The map
$$\psi:\quad {\mathbb Q}\to S^1,\qquad t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$$
maps rationals $x$, $y\in{\mathbb Q}$ that differ by an integer to the same point of $S^1$, hence maps all representants of an element $[x]\in G$ to the same point of $S^1$. It is easily verified that this $G$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of all complex numbers $e^{i\alpha}$ with $\alpha$ a rational multiple of $2\pi$, which is the same thing as the set of all $z\in S^1$ that can be an $n^{\rm th}$ root of unity for some $n\geq1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\Bbb Z+q)+(\Bbb Z+q)+\cdots( n \textrm{ terms})\cdots+(\Bbb Z+q)=\Bbb Z+nq=\Bbb Z+m=\Bbb Z.$$

Since $n(\Bbb Z+q)$ is the identity element in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$, then
$\Bbb Z+q$ has finite order in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Clearly I'm missing something here. Why is n(ℤ+q) the identity?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is the identity of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$. In general the identity of the quotient group $G/H$ is the coset $H$. @YipJungHon